# make case Sensitive RegularExpressionValidator's Regular expression for File Name

Tags: c#

When I am uploading multiple files using file upload Control I used RegularExpressionValidator to validate Files name.

My Regular expression : **([a-zA-Z0-9\s_$!^@\.()-:])+(.jpeg|.jpg|.gif|.png|.mp4|.mpg|.mpeg|.avi|.webm|.wmv|.mov)$**
It Works.
but I want to make this regular expression as Case Sensitive extension.

means it should allow ".JPG", ".GIF" so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.
but it works with `[jJ][pP][eE][gG]|.[jJ][pP][gG]|.[gG][iI][fF]` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make it case INsensitive, right?

You can use the regular expression options:

```
Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: "but I want to make this regular expression as Case Sensitive", "means it should allow ".JPG", ".GIF" so on".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?i)` at the beginning to mark your regular expression as case **insensitive**. Here is an example for jpg/JPG/..

```
(?i)^[a-z0-9\s]+\.(jpg|jpeg)$
```

Note: you have to quote the dot '.' (otherwise it means 'any character'). Checkout https://regex101.com/ to validate your RegEx.